# Как указать тип для массива, который состоит из строк являющихся свойствами объекта?

Tags: javascript, typescript, frontend, типы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли как то в TypeScript указать тип для массива, таким образом, что бы описать, что он может состоять только из тех строк, которые являются свойствами определённого объекта?

Т.е. например если есть тип для объекта:

```
type T = {
   t:number,
   b:number
}
```

то массив может состоять только из строк:
't' и 'b'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы скорее всего ищите оператор `keyof`, он запрашивает набор ключей для определенного типа:

```
type T = {
  t: number;
  b: number;
}

const array: (keyof T)[] = ['t', 'b'];
```